# Integrating Jqwidget

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

I was wondering if it is possible to use 2 jqx widgets together. If it is how possible would I go about doing it. I was thinking of combining jqxGrid, and jqxTree to create  a Grid with headers, column, and cell, but configure the cell to behave like a tree something like [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nZ2xC/1/) . I understand that a TreeGrid does not exist yet, and that I can use grouping but it does not do what I need it to do. is one of the possiblity where I will have to add the row one by one using add row like this

```
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('addrow', null, []);
```

and then configure it or would I have to create everything manually like the Jsfiddleand then just apply the styling :(

**Update**

A possibility maybe to use the new [custom cell editing](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm?%28arctic%29#demos/jqxgrid/cellcustomediting.htm)

**Update 2**

TreeGrid is available: [TreeGrid Demos](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtreegrid/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think jqxGrid suits what you want to do. If I understand well, what you describe if much more like a tree. Each row in jqxGrid are different data, and there is no way to link one row with another.

If I was you, I would look to use only jqxTree. See if you can use the [API](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxtree/jquery-tree-api.htm) to fit your needs. If not, look for another tree component. In the jqWidgets library, jqxGrid is really well develop, but it is not the case for all the others components.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, jQWidgets would release a new [TreeGrid](http://www.jqwidgets.com/roadmap/) component within the next 2 weeks. That should probably be what you're looking for.